# Visual Studio 2017, Windows Forms and an HTML page in project

Tags: html, vb.net

Good morning,

I (think) I've search everywhere and I can't find an answer and I'm sure it's going to be a simnple one.

I have a main VB.net project that processes webrequest and xml response, connects to DB and saves data. Now, a functionality I need is to represent this data on a Gantt-style form and there is no solution that works well with windows forms.

I've found a site that has a set of Java libraries that take XML and represent charts of all types on a HTML page- it's commercial but the watermarked one will do for now.

So, my question: how on earth, in VB.NET, do I call/open this html page that is under my Solution Explorer and saved locally??  This page is totally independent from the rest of the funtions and variables, it's got it's own set of procedures that deal with the DB data saved, so there is no paramaters passed or anything.

Just call/open the HTML form from a VB.net windows form, on a Visual Studio 2017 solution.

Many thanks for your replies...

Comment: Use the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control.  You'll find it in the Toolbox in Visual Studio.

Comment: `Process.Start("Your path and page.htm")`

Comment: good stuff... many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a HTML document **inside** your Window's Forms application, you can use Window's forms [WebBrowser Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Once you create this controls in your Windows Forms application, you can set its URL property:

```
myWebBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://www.example.com/");
```

And then navigate to this URL whenever you wish:

```
myWebBrowser.Navigate();
```

---

If you want to open a **browser** with a specific URL, you can use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.example.com");
```

This will launch the user's default browser with the URL address you provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've thought about a webcontrol in the windows form, but I need this html page to be independent, being opened in the default browser. Thanks

Comment: I have, but it says that I need 15 points to publicly show the vote. You and @mary, and all that have bothred to answer, have my moral 100 points